# How can I custom multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this :

```
$a  = array('value' =>
    array(
        'lesson_id' => array('1','6'), 
        'knowledge_value' => array('2','7'), 
        'knowledge_description' => array('3','8'), 
        'skill_value' => array('4','9'), 
        'skill_description' => array('5','10')
    )
);
```

I want to change it to be like this :

```
$a = array('value' =>
    array(
        array(
            'lesson_id' => '1', 
            'knowledge_value' => '2', 
            'knowledge_description' => '3',
            'skill_value' => '4',
            'skill_description' => '5'
        ),
        array(
            'lesson_id' => '6', 
            'knowledge_value' => '7', 
            'knowledge_description' => '8',
            'skill_value' => '9',
            'skill_description' => '10'
        ),
    )
);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You first need to make some attempts. We'll glad to help you to fix your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you.

Comment: Well you are going to have to write some code! Did you try to write some code for this yet, if so please show it to us

Comment: Post some code of your own tries and I will post my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/Efg2Q)

Here is the snippet for you to work, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$temp = [];
$keys = array_keys($a['value']); // fetched all keys
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a['value']['lesson_id']); $i++) { // compared with first count of lession_id
    $temp['value'][] = array_combine($keys, array_column($a['value'], $i)); // combined key and values
}
```

[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Comment: Please let's keep SO clear of "Gimme code"-type questions by not answering them until the OP has at least shown us _some_ attempt.